# Expo background location tracking for IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation, location

I am using this tutorial in order to learn expo background location tracking: https://chafikgharbi.com/expo-location-tracking/, but background location tracking gets denied for IOS.

I tried adding this in app.json file

```
"infoPlist":{
        "NSLocationUsageDescription":"App requires location even when the App is backgrounded.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription":"App requires location even when the App is backgrounded.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription":"App requires location even when the App is backgrounded.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription":"App requires location even when the App is backgrounded.",
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "location",
          "fetch"
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.